# How to display sprites on a 2D canvas, using Unity 5 and C#

Tags: c#, unity

I want to show a mini-map on the screen, but I don't have any idea to how to paint something in a panel on a canvas by code. The mini-map would look like this prototype I made some time ago, in Visual Studio.

[image: The mini-map displaying in the bottom right corner.]

I've tried instantiating a prefab image, but couldn't get it to work. I have two problems.

Firstly, I have 25 `Image` objects created in the scene, and 25 in the `PlayerController` script, but I can't get it to change the sprite. I am currently declaring them as follows:

```
public Image minimap0, minimap1, minimap2, minimap3, minimap4, minimap5, 
        minimap6, minimap7, minimap8, minimap9, minimap10, minimap11, 
        minimap12, minimap13, minimap14, minimap15, minimap16, minimap17, 
        minimap18, minimap19, minimap20, minimap21, minimap22, minimap23, 
        minimap24;
```

Lastly, I don't know how to change all 25 object sprites with a `for` loop, similar to the code that follows:

```
public void DrawMiniMap() {
    // mapXCord = miniMapPanel.transform.position.y;
    // mapXCord = 0;
    // mapYCord = 0;

    mapY = playerYPost - 2;
    int contadorArray = 0;
    Vector2 position = new Vector2 (mapXcord, mapYCord);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        mapX = playerXPos - 2;
        string actualMiniMap = "minimap" + contadorArray;

        // mapXCord = miniMapPanel.transform.position.x;

        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            position = new Vector2 (mapXCord, mapYCord);

            if (MapCreator.mapa [mapX, mapY] == 0) {                  
            } else if (MapCreator.mapa [mapX, mapY] == 1) {
            } else if (mapX == playerXPos && mapY == playerYPos) {
                if (playerOrientation == 'n') {
                } else if (playerOrientation == 'e') {
                } else if (playerOrientation == 's') {
                } else if (playerOrientation == 'w') {
                } 
            }
            // mapXCord += 15;
            contadorArray += 1;
        }
        // mapYCord += 15;
    }
}
```

The map is stored in an array for checking positions.

Comment: --Edits added--

Answer (score -1):

Under canvas create empty GameObject, add Image component, assign sprite to Image.sprite

Comment: if he is using a second camera for the minimap he will need to use Raw Image instead of Image.

Comment: No, the minimap will be a 5x5 grid displayed on a canvas, i will not use a second camera for that. Then, i should make 25 empty game objects and update them as I needed, or there is a better way for that? (the map itself is a grid, making a dungeon rpg game)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/nFr6sDK.png the minimap would look like this (bottom right corner, this was done time ago in Visual Studio)

Comment: Then you will need 25 sprite objects. In UI terminology they are named Image. so right click on canvs ->UI->image. I suggest that you parent them to a single empty object that has a Grid Layout Group. This will allow you to easily set up the grind. After that you need to update the Images accordingly ofc.

Comment: Mm, this is like basic steps you have to do either manually or programmatically. When doing manually you can also create image with GameObject > UI > Image, then drag and drop the sprite on it in Inspector. If you are doing this at runtime you can create a prefab of your Image GameObject and use Instantiate() function to spawn them.

Comment: Uri's way is the way to go, I was going to make the next comment like his. :))

Comment: I can't make this to work! Have two problems, I have 25 Image objects created in the scene and 25 in the playercontroller script http://imgur.com/Lxrdplj , but I can't make to change its sprite, and also, I don't know how to change all 25 objects sprite with a "for" loop (the foor will look like this http://imgur.com/qfi1Ht1 ). The map is stored in an array for checking positions.

Comment: This is a seperate question please make a new question about iterating over 25 game object and I will explain how to do it.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/120611/how-to-iterate-over-25-sprite-objects-unity-5-c here it is