# How to iterate over 25 Sprite Objects (Unity 5 - C#)

Tags: unity

I wanna show a minimap on the screen. The minimap would look like this (bottom right corner, this was done time ago in Visual Studio):

[image: Minimap]

Have two problems with that, I have 25 Image objects created in the scene and 25 in the playercontroller script:

```
public Image minimap0, minimap1, minimap2, minimap3, ... , minimap24;
```

but I can't make to change its sprite, and also, I don't know how to change all 25 objects sprite with a "for" loop (the foor will look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpCLN.jpg ).

The map is stored in an array for checking positions.

Comment: Are you familiar with arrays, eg. `public Image[] mapTiles` or `Image[,] mapTiles = new Image[5, 5]`?

Comment: It's really great that you want to add code to your question, but it would be far better when you would put it into the question as text and not post it as an image. That way people can directly copy&paste your code into their answer and correct any mistakes.